# String Array: Displaying Results

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-places-api

I was thinking that I could take in the user inputs which I get from the two `AutoCompleteTextView` and show it in as a result for which there is a `TableLayout`.

The two inputs that the `AutoCompleteTextView` takes is **My Location** and **Destination** from the users. The complexity comes from the type of input that the `AutoCompleteTextView` generates. The `AutoCompleteTextView` uses the `PlacesAutoComplete` from Google, therefore I am working with an inputs like *Jamal, Kathmandu, Central Region, Nepal* and maybe *Kalanki, Kathmandu, Central Region, Nepal*. What I would want the `TableLayout` to reflect is **Results: From ... To ...**

My question is how can I just take in the first part of the string in *Jamal, Kathmandu, Central Region, Nepal* which is just *Jamal* for the `TableLayout` to display a the results like **Results: From Jamal to Kalanki**. Being very new to android I sort of have a vague idea, the code that I tried looks like this.

```
String[] from;
String[] to;
//pulling the auto complete text view
from =  location.getString().toText();
to = destination.getString().toText();
//referencing the text view inside the table layout
results.setText(new StringBuilder().append("Results from"+from[0]).append(" to"+to[0]));
```

This code obviously does not work as it prompts me to change `from` to a `String`. I really do not know what is going on. Please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
String[] from = new String[]{location.getString().toText()};
String[] to  = new String[]{destination.getString().toText()};
results.setText(new StringBuilder().append("Results from"+from[0]).append(" to"+to[0]));
```

Or

```
String from;
String to;
from =  location.getString().toText();
to = destination.getString().toText();
results.setText(new StringBuilder().append("Results from"+from).append(" to"+to));
```

Hope its help.

Comment: Not sure what those array declarations are meant to do, but they won't compile.

Comment: well it did work but I am getting the full part of the address. Like if the input is `Kalanki, Kathmandu, Central Region, Nepal` I would only want to get `Kalanki` in my result display ... With the code ... I get the full address

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a String to a String[]. That will not work.

```
from =  location.getString().toText();
```

Assign them to a `String` and execute this.

```
results.setText(new StringBuilder().append("Results from"+from).append(" to"+to));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign `String` to `String[]` (**String and String array are not the same!**)

Use them as a String:

```
String from =  location.getString().toText();

results.setText(new StringBuilder().append("Results from"+from).append(" to"+to));
```

Comment: I was using the String array so that I could modify the user input ... like if they were to enter an address like `Kalanki, Kathmandu, Central Region, Nepal` or maybe `Kalanki Kathmandu` I would only want to show them back the 1st word, which in this case is `Kalanki`

Comment: But location.getString().toText(); returns a String, not String array. You can create a new String modified as you wish and show it to the user.

Comment: hmmm ... i dont get you ... sorry ... if you could give me an example ??

Answer (score 0):

```
    String from_split = location.getText().toString();
    String to_split = destination.getText().toString();
    if(from_split.contains(","))
    {
        from = from_split.split(",");
    }
    else
    {
        from = from_split.split(" ");
    }
    if(to_split.contains(","))
    {
        to = to_split.split(",");
    }
    else
    {
        to = to_split.split(" ");
    }
    results.setText(new StringBuffer().append(from[0]).append(" to "+to[0]));
```

I guess I found the answer to displaying the result the way I wanted to.